# Dictionary vs pivot Table and some office issues

Tags: vba, dictionary

In company when I currently work we have big issue with MS excel stability,  hence my question below.

Recently I just learned about excel Dictonary code.

I know pivot tables and how they work.
sadly the issue is not with pivot themselves but with excel. (IT dept. is working on the issue for 3 weeks now, and we dont know when / if they gonna fix it)

Hence my big ask for thi community:
I would need a userform working with the dictonary.

What I would need is to create a code that could work as pivot table but using dictonaries (since theoreticaly they are faster and are outside of VBA / excel basic in-build option)

so?

1. Can some1 help in creating such code?
2. Is this the right option?

I would like to see a userform where I can choose my Table(ctrl+T) headers to choose by which header i want to sum values up, and ofc I would have to be able to choose a column by which the dictonary summing is working on.

Comment: I am afraid "excel Dictionary" cannot be even compared with Pivot Table. Can you edit your question and show us a piece of code using such a dictionary? Just to be sure that you understand what such an object can do...

Comment: It's not possible to answer this question without details of what you want to do.  In any case, if Excel is really "unstable" (and it would help to explain exactly what you mean by that) then anything which is still running in Excel may not provide any real improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for answering.
Lets start then.

I watched ExcelMacroMastery videos regarding dictionaries,
In this example, he used them to make a basic sum exactly like the basic functionality of Pivot table.
So since that's the basic use where I work I wish to have a dictionary macro from which I can choose the column by which I get unique values and 2nd column with a sum from the second provided column from a table.

the issue is: if I show any file or any example this could result in macro working for this specific case, and I would like it to be able to choose by Table's (CTRL+T) headers for the unique values and to use some way(like a dropdown menu) to choose the column by which the sum can happen.

This instability is due to 32 bit office suite 365 working n 64 bi PCs/ laptops and recent company update made it even worse, now there is an issue with even basic save file option.
Not to mention excel crashing for no apparent reason.

So to sum up,
I need dictionaries to kinda step up and replace basic summarizing functionality of an pivot table.

or to replace this non pivot way:

1. use unique function to determine unique values from specified column (non-table object sadly)
2. Use sumif or sumoifs function to summarize the specified amount/value for that unique list.

//EDIT:
I kinda found what I was looking for thus the edit.
Im showing the link to the file I wish to change a bit:
https://app.monstercampaigns.com/c/s0iavndiopijkrar8ghp/

to this file I wish to add a user form by which the headers of the report will be chosen from source data, and by which the sum will occur.

Comment: I think you can just follow the contents of youtube.